# Difference in meaning: "my skills" vs "my particular skills"

Tags: meaning, difference

A worker is dismissed from job; he is saying what his managers told him about the dismissal.

> They said they did not need so many people with my particular skills

I wonder why the worker said *my particular skills*, whereas *my skills* would simply be quite clear.

Is there any difference between *my particular skills* and *my skills*?

Comment: It's pretty much a set phrase. Google "particular skills" and compare the famous quotation: "I don't know who you are. I don't know what you want. If you are looking for ransom I can tell you I don't have money, but what I do have are **a very particular set of skills**. Skills I have acquired over a very long career. Skills that make me a nightmare for people like you." (Luc Besson, Robert Mark Kamen)

Answer (score 1):

I think that with **particular** he just want to emphasize that he as got some "specific" skills.

But in reality, there are no particular differences between the two.

Comment: _Specific_ or _exact_ rather than _unique_. If his skills were unique, there could not be 'so many people' with them!

Comment: You are right, that's exactly what i want to say. Thanks @KateBunting. I've edited the response.

Answer (score 0):

In this sentence, looks like, with **particular**, he wants to refer to his skills specific to his job. He can be having multiple other skills (let's say painting, dancing) which may not be relevant to his job (Let's say a chef).